# How can I make a control visible when WindowState is Maximized and collapsed when Normal?

Tags: wpf, controls, visibility

This is my view, I want to collapse the second `Rectange` in the `Button` when windowstate is normal and vice versa.  Mistakenly I changed the command name as `ShowCommand`, well I'm trying it but can't do it.

xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Width="30"  Height="20" Margin="0,30" Command="{Binding MinimizeCommand}" >
            <Rectangle Width="8" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Width="30" Height="20" Command="{Binding ShowCommand}" >
            <Grid >
                <Rectangle Width="8" Height="8" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Margin="0,3,5,3" />                        
                <Rectangle Visibility="{Binding MaximizeButtonVisibility}" Stroke="Black"
                           x:Name="RectMaxButton" Margin="10,0,0,8" Width="8" Height="8"
                           StrokeThickness="2" />
            </Grid>
        </Button>
        <Button Width="30" Height="20" Margin="0,30" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"
                FontWeight="Bold">X</Button>
    </WrapPanel>           
</StackPanel>
```

cs:

```
public ICommand ShowCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_showCommand == null)
            _showCommand = new RelayCommand(para => CanExit(), param => ToggleMaximizeWindwo());
        return _showCommand;
    }
}

public Visibility MaximizeButtonVisibility
{           
    get
    {
        this._maximizeButtonVisibility = Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        return this._maximizeButtonVisibility; 
    }
    set
    {
        this._maximizeButtonVisibility = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("MaximizeButtonVisility");
    }
}

private void ToggleMaximizeWindwo()
{
    if (Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        MaximizeButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        MaximizeButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) make a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and 2) bind to the WindowState of the Window.  Overthinking this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in your MaximizeButtonVisibility setter in the OnPropertyChanged. You have it as "MaximizeButtonVisility" when it should be "MaximizeButtonVisibility".

Comment: well its works fine at first start but i want this visibility changed when ever WindowState changes as I've done this MaximizeButtonVisibility property, but its not getting effect after first start, am doing Maximize/Minimize small recatange visiblit/hidden when WindowState changes.

Comment: I did correct that thing but still it was not working so I did put "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" after binding and it worked. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful for someone, but if you were to consistently use
`OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MaximizeButtonVisibility));`
Then the name cannot be wrong, and this will also continue to work if the property is renamed.